# Filter conditionally in a pipe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, pipe

I have a lot of data frames, each with several columns. Two of these columns are `time` and `value`.

**Minimal example**

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- approx(seq(1,10,1), c(1,5,7,11,4,12,30, 20, 10, 9)) %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      rename(time = x, value = y)
```

**Goal**

I want to remove all rows from each data frame, starting at the first time `value > 10`.

When the data frame contains `values > 10`, a solution would be the following:

```
df <- df %>% 
         filter(row_number() <= first(which(value > 10))-1)
```

However, there are also data frames where the `value` does not exceed `10`, e.g.,

```
df <- approx(seq(1,10,1), c(1,5,7,1,4,2,1, 2, 1, 9)) %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      rename(time = x, value = y)
```

In this case, the data frame should not be filtered (because the `value` threshold is not reached). When I use the `filter` solution from above, however, it returns an empty data frame.

**Question**

How would you solve this problem inside a `dplyr` pipe? Is it possible to do conditional filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a conditional statement in `filter` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    filter(if(any(value > 10)) row_number() <= which.max(value > 10)-1 else TRUE)
```

Writing the same logic in `slice` :

```
df %>% 
   slice(if(any(value > 10)) seq_len(which.max(value > 10)-1) else seq_len(n()))
```

**Microbenchmarking**

In terms of speed, there isn't a large difference between `filter` and `slice`:

```
df <- approx(seq(1,10^5,1), 
             round( runif(10^5, min = 1, max = 10^10) ) ) %>% 
      as.data.frame()

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  filter = df %>% filter(if(any(value > 10)) row_number() <= which.max(value > 10)-1 else TRUE),
  slice = df %>% slice(if(any(value > 10)) seq_len(which.max(value > 10)-1) else seq_len(n())), times = 10000)

Unit: microseconds
  expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 filter 551.522 570.2715 655.7250 586.3530 621.5590 13575.81 10000
 slice 614.276 633.6840 735.0398 654.2455 695.3795 14123.43 10000
```